# Image skeleton formula

Tags: matlab, image-processing

in order to get the skeleton of an image, I found this formula,

```
 Sk(X) = [(X ⊖ kB)] − [(X ⊖ kB) ◦ B]
```

What I don't understand here is the - sign in the formula. For example if I use Matlab, and the image becomes a matrix, should I understand that I must perform matrix - matrix ... ?
Thank you very much.

Edit:
Notations:
⊖ means erode
◦ means erode then dilate
k means numbers of erode times

Comment: Where did you find the formula? Could you give a link so that we can understand what the symbols mean? And what are `kB` and `B`?

Comment: Looks like Lantuéjoul's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_skeleton#Lantu.C3.A9joul.27s_formula

Comment: from my book, i've just added explanation for those symbols, is it fine now?

Comment: Judging from the wikipedia page I would indeed say the - stands for minus. However, this question may be more suitable for math.stackexchange.com. Note that if you are unsure about how to do this in matlab, you can indeed just do matrix-matrix by using the - sign. It will be an element wise calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does mean `matrix - matrix`. This is standard  [matrix subtraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition). In Matlab, if you have matrices `A` and `B`, matrix subtraction is simply `A - B`.

Comment: This is simply a direct simplification of representing elements in sets as having some intensity X which is mapped to a matrix (the elements that were not in the set are represented as `1 - X` then, for example).

Answer (score 3):

When you deal with numbers, `a - b` means subtraction. When you are dealing with sets, `A - B` means subtraction too, another representation for it is `A \ B` (set difference). If your set `A` is represented by `{x1, x2, x3, x4}` and `B = {x3, x4}`, then `A - B = {x1, x2}`.